# Proving OP(L) is regular

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions, closure-properties

I did some searching before I decided to ask this question and there was nothing similar to my question that helped me. So I came to CS stack-exchange for hints. 
So, I am currently working on a proof to show that if $L$ is regular then $OP(L)$ is also regular without the use of pumping lemma. For the sake of this question, I am using $\{0,1\}$ as alphabet.

$$OP(L) = \{w \mid wz ∉ L \text{ for every } z ∈ \{0,1\}^+ \}.$$

At the moment, I have a hard time starting the proof. What I understand is that, if $L$ is regular then we can define a DFA that can decide $L$. And then we can define another machine for $OP(L)$ with every transition from $M$ along with $\epsilon$-transitions.

Am I on the right track? I could really use some hints.

Comment: Crosspost with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2470482/proving-opl-is-regular

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider a DFA for $L$, and some word $w$. Suppose that upon reading $w$, the DFA reaches some state $q$. Is knowing $q$ enough for deciding whether $w \in OP(L)$?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? The way i am thinking about this is that the state q also has to be in the machine for OP(L).

Comment: You asked for a hint - I gave you a hint.

Comment: That's true but the hint is not hitting the home yet. If you'd be kind enough and explain it in like 2-3 sentences that'd be much appreciated.

Comment: As a further hint, the answer to my question is "Yes".

Comment: Don't expect it to hit home immediately. Solving math exercises often takes time.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility is the use closure properties of the regular languages. The new language $\mathrm{OP}(L)$ can be written using concatenation and Boolean operations using the original $L$ and simple regular languages.

Comment: But then that won't be a full proof, would it?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be a full proof? We are allowed to use known results in proofs.